# Mac: write 2 lines as a script

Tags: macos, shell

I dont know how to write 2 commands (which I enter in terminal) as a script.
I wrote file "my.sh" with 2 lines, then double-clicked it.
I need ~/mydir path with tilde.

```
cd ~/mydir
make
```

File opens in Xcode editor.
How to write it OK and run by dbl-click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it as a `.command`:

**my.command**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/mydir
make
```

If it doesn't do anything upon double-clicking you might need to `chmod` it:

```
chmod +x my.command
```